# The Issues Report Plugin does not retrieve metrics

Tags: sonarqube

I have a problem when I run the Issues Report Plugin on the multi-module project. I noted that the documentation indicated that the plugin is incompatible with this kind of project.

Nevertheless, I tried to run a `sonar-runner` dry run on one of the modules using its `projectKey` and `projectName` *(retrieved from the widget Description)*. Unfortunately, the plugin has not retrieved metrics previously analyzed for this module. All anomalies are marked as new.

Is there a way to ensure I get the right values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dry run mode for SonarQube analyses on multi-module projects suffers from limitations, which are all fixed in the upcoming 3.6.1 version of SonarQube.

See the following ticket: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4265

And just to be clear: the Issues Report Plugin does not export measures of metrics, it only exports issues.

Comment: _Merci_ for your reply. About metrics, it was an abuse of language on my part. Sorry.